# Can't pull a microsoft's docker container

Tags: docker, powershell, containers, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

I tried pulling a docker container from microsoft's containers registry.

I got the powershell commands from: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-businesscentral

These are it:

$artifactUrl = Get-BcArtifactUrl -type sandbox -country us -select latest

New-BCContainer -accept_eula -containerName test -artifactUrl $artifactUrl

This is the error message that I get:

[Error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJgWa.png)

Does anyone know why this is not working? I've done this like 2 months ago and I got no errors.
I appretiate any help, and sorry if this is simple or was already asked before, I'm new with containers and powershell commands and I searched for similar problems with no luck.

Comment: looks like the image has been removed if you visit the link present in the command and so you get the error that the image is not found: https://bcartifacts.azureedge.net/onprem/17.0.16993.0/us%20mcr.microsoft.com/dynamicsnav:10.0.19042.630. btw, you don't pull `containers`, you pull `docker images`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I read somewhere that microsoft rearranged some stuff regarding their images, but it seems like they haven't updated their documentation, guess I'll have to wait?

Comment: Please include text formatted code/logs in your question, not an external link to a picture of text. Questions should remain valid when links to bad, and text data should be able to be copy/paste by those reproducing your issue and search engines.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will keep that in mind for the next time, the problem was already solved by kaspermoerch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still running NavContainerHelper, which has been deprecated ([as described here](https://freddysblog.com/2021/03/01/navcontainerhelper-doesnt-work-anymore/)).

You need to switch to BcContainerHelper.

As described in the link above the process for switching is as follows:

1. Remove all containers (`Get-NavContainers | Remove-NavContainer`)
2. Uninstall all versions of NavContainerHelper (`UnInstall-Module NavContainerHelper -allversions`)
3. Restart PowerShell and check that NavContainerHelper is gone (else repeat step 2)
4. Reset Docker to factory settings (to remove all images)
5. Remove `c:\ProgramData\NavContainerHelper`
6. Install BcContainerHelper (`Install-Module BcContainerHelper -force`)