# Does the imagename and artifacturl in creating containerimages in Azure need to be the same?

Tags: azure-container-instances, dynamics-business-central

I am running the following in Powershell to create a Business Central Container in Azure

```
 $imageName = "mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral/sandbox:16.2.13509.23270-us";
 $resourceGroup = "RG1";
 $location = "westeurope"
 $containerName = "d365bcrg1"
 $dnsName = "d365bcrg1.westeurope.azurecontainer.io"
 $artifactUrl = Get-BCArtifactUrl -version 16.2 -country us -select Latest

 az group create --name $resourceGroup --location $location

 az container create -g $resourceGroup -n $containerName --image $imageName --os-type Windows --cpu 2 
 --memory 16 --ip-address public -e artifactUrl=$artifactUrl ACCEPT_EULA=Y USESSL=N ClickOnce=Y
 publicDnsName=$dnsName --dns-name-label $containerName `
--ports 80 7046 7047 7048 7049 8080
```

But i keep getting the error:

```
The image 'mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral/sandbox:16.2.13509.23270-us' in container group 
'd365bcrg1' is not accessible. 
Please check the image and registry credential.
```

What registry credential ?
Not sure why this is happening , need some help with this its been almost 2 days ?

Modified script:

```
 $imageName = "mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral:10.0.19042.630";
 $location = "westus"
 $dnsName = "d365bcrg1.westus.azurecontainer.io"
 $artifactUrl = Get-BCArtifactUrl -version 16.2 -country us -select Latest

az container create -g RG1 -n d365bcrg1 --image $imageName 
-- os-type Windows --cpu 2  --memory 16 --ip-address public -e 
  artifactUrl=$artifactUrl ACCEPT_EULA=Y USESSL=N ClickOnce=Y 
   publicDnsName=$dnsName --dns-name-label d365bcrg1 --ports 80 443 7046 
   7048 7049 8080
```

Comment: Any update? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66544297/cant-pull-a-microsofts-docker-container) help you?

Comment: I am new to all of this and trying to work it out.. I am confused with the $imageName . and $artifacturl. Are they related in any way ? I have tried following some examples but with no luck. All i want is to spin up a Business Central container in Azure, not a VM because i need a number of people to connect for development and a VM will require certificates . Is my location westeurope wrong ? Also i want an image that wont give me the error , it is outdated ?

Comment: Where do you get this image URL?

Comment: you mean where did i get it from ? I was reading Freddys blog

Comment: Yes, where do you get it from? any link? I just find this https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-businesscentral

Comment: Yes if i use the following mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral:10.0.19042.630 I get the error:      Unsupported windows image version. Supported versions are 'Windows Server 2016 - Before 2B, Windows Server 2019 - Before 2B, Windows Server 
2016 - After 2B, Windows Server 2019 - After 2B, Windows Server, Version 1903 - After 2B, Windows Server, Version 2004'

Comment: I have modified the script above to a different location, westus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230072/discussion-between-abbey-and-nancy-xiong).

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the image is not publicly accessible or in the wrong format or does not exist. Read [Microsoft Container Registry (MCR)](https://github.com/microsoft/containerregistry) for more details.

[image]

From [Guidance for using the official Microsoft Container Registry (MCR) endpoints](https://github.com/microsoft/containerregistry/blob/master/docs/mcr-endpoints-guidance.md):

> If you experience issues with pulling artifacts from MCR, contact
> [Microsoft Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/). You can also [submit an issue](https://github.com/login?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmicrosoft%2Fcontainerregistry%2Fissues%2Fnew) in the
> official MCR GitHub repository.

For a private image, you need to provide the credentials to log in container image registry server. It's recommended to [create a container image from application source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-app) and [create an Azure container registry and upload your image to ACR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-acr) and [deploy the azure container instance from your registry image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-using-azure-container-registry).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Containers are not supported for running Business Central containers.

You can read more about it in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/navcontainerhelper/issues/670) on GitHub.

If you want to run in Azure, you need to use a Windows Server with Containers VM.

Comment: Not sure that is entirely true. I have ran up one before and managed to connect. But for some reason I cant get the correct image , it keeps giving "not supported in location error"  Have a look at the following link     https://svirlan.com/2019/01/01/how-to-generate-azure-containers-instances-loaded-with-business-central-in-minutes/     I have followed this link but the imagname is probably outdated by now and the artifact has probably changed, Thats what I am having issue with.   I prefer not to use a VM cause i need multiple developers to connect to it which will require certificates.

Comment: It might have worked previously when the version specific images were available in Microsofts registry. It is not (and has never been) officially supported.

Comment: so would you knwo how i can get a business central container in Azure with the above scripts at all ?

Comment: You might be able to run it on an Azure Container if you build the images and then upload them to your own image registry. I do however think the best solution would be to use an Azure VM with traefik as mentioned in the GitHub issue I linked.